# VBA: Reading excel data into word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am making a simple form that extract the data from my excel sheet, such as name, date of birth, and address. And inserting them into my word form, I am doing 20-30 sheets everytime, so I think it might be able to save the copying & pasting time.

I tried to follow this tutorial: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/integrate-excel-data-word-document/
And created a button with a simple label named `m_name`, for member's name. But it tells me `Compile error: User-defined type not defined`.  And flaged on line 1.

I am using Word 2003, (I am not able to find the Tools > Reference as the guide was asking for). I am not sure if it is related to this error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("U:\test.xls")
ThisDocument.m_name.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Member's Data").Cells(3, 3)

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You need a reference to the "Microsoft Excel [version] Object library".  There should be a *Tools>>References* menu option in the Word VB Editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's very important to set references according to the tutorial.

However, change these two lines:

```
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
```

to:

```
Dim objExcel As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

and the code should work, too.

Comment: This works wonder! Are there any explanations to this, or it is just how it works?

Comment: If you can't set references according to tutorial (which is called 'early-binding') you could do it with technique proposed by me (which is called 'late-binding'). For further information please [read this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115/en-us)